# How to improve performance in this DML statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, insert-update

Hi
This statements are executed in Stored Procedure. I am passing parameters and It is doing multiple updates and inserts. 
I will appreciate some suggestions to 
-improve the performance, 
-reduce the execution time 
-and improvements in code structure. 
There are three different tables: Table_01, Table_02, Table_03.

```
INSERT INTO Table_01(
    TestID,     
    TestData,
    CurrentDate,
    UserID,
    Status
) VALUES (
    @testID,        
    @testData,
    @iDateTime,
    @userID,
    @Status
)

IF (@Status = 1) 
BEGIN 

    DELETE FROM
        Table_02
    WHERE 
        TestID = @testID

    UPDATE Table_03
    SET
        Status = 1,
        Date = @iDateTime,
        Work = 0
    WHERE
        TestID = @testID
END
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. Before we can suggest anything we'll need to have a look at your table definitions.

Comment: That's pretty straightforward, how long is it taking to run? or do you have some looping in there that you are not showing?

Comment: @HLGEM: There is no loop. but just curious if there is any scope to improve above structure... That can give a bit of more performance

Comment: Since that should take milliseconds at best, I'm not sure why you want to imporve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really much to tweak to be honest: it's straightforward code, nothing fancy

You can add a transaction so it all writes succeed or all writes fail.

If you find the code slow then I'd look at indexes on TestID and do you have triggers